# Responsive text over an image html

Tags: html, css, responsive

I added a line of text over an image, but when I change the screen size, the text change position, I want the Text to stay fixed on the screen even when I change screen size and make it responsive. I want to ask also if I want to insert a link button below the text what can I do to make it responsive to adapt all screen size and stay centered.  Can you help me with that? Codes below. Thank you!!!
-Alessandro

```css
@font-face {
  src: url(fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf);
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  src: url(/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf);
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

header {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: left;
  position: sticky;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
}

nav {
  background-color: rgb(219, 138, 31);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  /* Per togliere i puntini della lista */
  margin: 0;
  /* Toglie distanza laterale */
  padding: 0;
  /* Toglie distanza laterale */
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Toglie le decorazioni testo*/
  color: white;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Li dispone orizzonatlamente */
  padding: 25px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

.immaginehome {
  position: relative;
}

.immagine {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.benvenuto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 3em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-          scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Museo</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <!-- Header -->
    <a href="link" class="logo"><strong>Allo.</strong></a>

  </header>

  <nav>
    <!-- Barra Navigazione -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="link">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="link">IL MUSEO</a></li>
      <li><a href="link">TICKET</a></li>
      <li><a href="link">INFO</a></li>
      <li><a href="link">DOVE SIAMO</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="immaginehome">
    <img src="immagini/image.jpg" alt="immaginemuseo" class="immagine">
    <div class="benvenuto">BENVENUTO</div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You would need to post a bit more of your code for me to be sure, but you could start by adding `position: relative;` to the **immaginehome** element CSS.

Comment: Fixed, my bad!!

Comment: @AlessandroTodaro did my answer portray your desired solution?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have to close your div with the `id` `immaginehome`. Then remove your absolute positioning on `benvenuto` and make the position `relative`. Then add `width: 100%;` to that div containing the text, and add `text-align: center;` to center align it. I used a dummy image to demonstrate.

```css
@font-face {
src: url(fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf);
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
src: url(/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf);
}

body{
text-align: center;
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI',  Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

header{
padding: 15px;
background-color:transparent;
text-align: left;
position: sticky;
height: auto;
top: 0;
}

.logo{
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
font-size: 50px;


}

nav{
background-color: rgb(219, 138, 31);
position: sticky;
top: 0;
background-color: burlywood;
}
nav ul{
list-style: none; /* Per togliere i puntini della lista */
margin: 0; /* Toglie distanza laterale */
padding: 0; /* Toglie distanza laterale */
}

nav li a{
text-decoration: none; /* Toglie le decorazioni testo*/ 
color: white;
}

nav li{
display: inline-block; /* Li dispone orizzonatlamente */
padding: 25px;
}

nav li:hover{
background-color: gray;
}

.immaginehome{
position: relative;
}

.immagine{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}

.benvenuto{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-          scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Museo</title>
</head>
<body>

<header> <!-- Header -->
    <a href="link" class="logo"><strong>Allo.</strong></a>

</header>

<nav> <!-- Barra Navigazione -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="link">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">IL MUSEO</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">TICKET</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">INFO</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">DOVE SIAMO</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="immaginehome">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x500/000/fff" alt="immaginemuseo" class="immagine">
<div class="benvenuto">BENVENUTO</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** OP updated the code.

Answer (score -1):

Looking for something like this? You need a container to overlay the items. Add the image on top, then you add the text. Now simply position the text element with `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` and remove `inset`.

```css
/* CSS */
.container {
  position: relative; /* this is important! */
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* do your stuff to position it as needed */
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
   <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="">
   <h2 class=title>Title</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Notes in css are written with `/* - */` not `//` Also, notes in HTML are written like `<!-- ~ -->`.

Comment: I want the text stay over the image

Comment: That is what it does. If you mean something else, please explain more in detail. (i added a "real" image so you can see)